# How can we display a string by parcing first word in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For eg. We have this string and I want first word to be parsed and display rest of the string. 
Vendor IE02_02_11 is not defined in company code.

Comment: Can't understand your question. Please give a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

use this code  for first character

```
String version= "IE02_02_11";
int length=  version.length();
char firstChar=version.chartAt(0);
```

and for rest of string use this code.

```
String restString = version.subString(1,length-1);
```

subString will cut the string from 1 to its last character and then it will save in restString.

Answer (score 0):

`import re
sentence = "Vendor IE02_02_11 is not defined in company code."
if "Vendor" in sentence:
   re.sub("Vendor",'',c,1)`

output:IE02_02_11 is not defined in company code.

Is this what u wanted,if not please give an example